# How to solve Fatal Error: 10 out of resources in DELL PowerEdge 2850?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, dell, dell-poweredge

I facing the problem since 2 days. I am trying to **install VShere 6.0/5.5/5.0**. But I cannot. It throws error

**Error**

> Error Loading /s.v00
>
> Fatal Error: 10 out of resources

My system Raid configuration is I make it 2 array, I configured **RAID 1 and RAID 5**

Hard drive : 300GB * 6

Bios Version : A07

RAM : 2GB * 4 slot, Total 8 GB

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The most current version of ESXi that's supported on the Dell PowerEdge 2850 is version 4.1 U3. Perhaps you should use hardware that's supported for the version of ESXi you want to install.

Comment: @joeqwerty the weirdest thing is before I did the installation 5.0 on the same server. And It was working fine for 1 year

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while I was trying to install VMWare ESXi 7.7 on my EC2 instance (z1d.metal) using VMWare WorkStation player.

1. In WorkStation PLayer - I have powered oFF the VM.
2. Edit - Virtual Machine settings and increased the RAM usage for this VM.
3. And then restarted the installation of ESXi. It went through successfully.